# How to get process information of usernames in /etc/passwd in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, ps

I have extracted all usernames of /etc/passwd by command below and save them in another file:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" {print $5} > temp.txt
```

and now I want to get process information of each username of "temp.txt" but I don't know how to do it.
Furthermore how to examine who have logged in the system during the last day and which command(s) s/he has executed?

Comment: `top -b -n1 > temp.txt`

Comment: There are no users on the system which are not in `/etc/passwd`. You simply need a listing of all processes.

Comment: Your second question should simply be posted as a separate question, but Stack Overflow is a programming site, so it's not on-topic here. Try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: If you want itemized by user, `cut -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 ps -u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
for u in $(<temp.txt); do echo "$i processes:"; pgrep -fl -u "$u"; done
```